# Signs of eigenvectors : Dual PCA

Tags: pca, linear-algebra

I'm trying to perform a DUAL PCA with numpy, this is are the steps I'm following:

**0 - Standardize X, where X is for instance (m,n)**

**1 - Find eigenvalues, eigenvectors of X.T dot X**

Plot the projections (2D in this case)

In this is case the projections are points ...

**2 - Find eigenvalues, eigenvectors of X dot X.T**

Plot the projections (2D in this case)

In this case I'm projecting the arrows.

The problem I'm facing the graph obtained doesn't make sense, I think the problem is that the eigenvectors of *X dot X.T* & *X.T dot X* should have the same sign which isn't the case.

Is there a way to detect if the eigenvectors of *X dot X.T* & *X.T dot X* are pointing in **opposite** direction or insure that they point in the same direction ?

Thank you

Comment: The sign of the eigenvectors is arbitrary. You can read more about this in many posts about PCA on this site. You can detect same vs. opposite direction using the dot product. If $u$ and $v$ are unit vectors, then $u \cdot v = 1$ if $u=v$, and $-1$ if $u = -v$. A small tolerance around $1$ or $-1$ might be needed to account for machine precision/rounding error issues.

Comment: u is an (n,1) and v (m,1) matrix, I can't perform the dot product. I don't think you understand my question ,u is going to be the eigenvector of X.T dot X and v the eigenvectors of X . X.T